# What does this "proof" tell us about the Laplace transformation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

An exercise in the book stated "Find $2$ functions $f_1 \not =f_2$ such that $L\{f_1\}=L\{f_2\}$. Now I think I know the answer ($f_1=f_2$ except at any number of discrete points) but previously I was so convinced that this can't happen that I wanted to see what happens if I try to prove that the Laplace transformation is one-to-one. Here is what I came up with:

Let $f'(t)$ and $g'(t)$ be functions such that $L(f'(t))=L(g'(t))$. In order to prove that the LaPlace transform is one-to one (at least for most "nice" functions), we need to prove that $f'(t)=g'(t)$

Let $F(s)=L(f(t))$ and $G(s)=L(g(t))$

$L(f'(t))=sF(s)-f(0)=L(g'(t))=sG(s)-g(0)$

$F(s)-G(s)=\dfrac {f(0)-g(0)}{s}$

$L^{-1}(F(s)-G(s))=L^{-1}(\dfrac {f(0)-g(0)}{s})$

$f(t)-g(t)=f(0)-g(0)$

$\dfrac {d}{dt} [f(t)-g(t)]=\dfrac {d}{dt} [f(0)-g(0)]$

$f'(t)-g'(t)=0$

$f'(t)=g'(t)$

So if it is correct, what does this proof imply exactly? Of course the Laplace transformation is not one-to-one, but what restrictions does this proof impose on the two functions other than $\int {f'dt}$ and $\int g' dt$ exist and $L(f)$ and $L(g)$ exist?

Comment: Unfortunately, this proof is not valid. Your move from $F(s) - G(s)$ to $f(t) - g(t)$ requires knowing that the inverse Laplace transform is well-defined on some class of functions, e.g. that Laplace is already $1-1$. It ends up assuming the conclusion.

Comment: @T.Bongers you should post this as an answer

Comment: @StellaBiderman It's rather incomplete and doesn't really address what the "right" class of functions is, so I'll leave it to someone else to write something nice in detail. I will suggest, however, that the OP look at Redheffer's differential equations book, because I seem to recall that it has a very nice discussion of all these matters.

Comment: @T.Bongers I would say that this "proof" doesn't tell us anything about it because it assumes its conclusion. Would you disagree?

Comment: Sure, but it does sorta point to what the correct result is. Feel free to take my comment and make it an answer.

Comment: If $f$ has a Laplace transform  ${\cal L} f$ and $g$ is equal to $f$ almost everywhere, then ${\cal L}g = {\cal L}f$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the confirmation of my answer, that's a neat way to put it.

Comment: @Ovi What copper.hat said is actually different from what you said. You can have a dense set of measure zero, for example $\{0\}\cup\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$